# Access via Guacamole

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have a successful working instance of Apache Guacamole working through docker on my server.  However, I'm trying to connect to my new ubuntu box (not a VM) through VNC, but guac is not allowing this to happen no matter what settings I use.

I was hoping to use the basic built-in screen sharing VNC option so that I don't have to install new dependencies etc.

In guac, I've tried the VNC connection with the static IP under hostname and 5901 as the port, the computer name with and without the port, and I've tried installing xRDP to connect via that, but I ran into issues where I have to reboot the computer every time I want to use when I am connected remotely during the day and then try to switch to using it directly at night.

Sorry, I'd ask this on the guac forums, but their listserv is a little confusing to navigate.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, mostly I'm wondering if anyone has an explanation of what should be filled out and where on the guacamole connection setup screen.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Here's how I solved it:

#### Enable Remote Desktop Sharing

To begin, we first need to make sure that remote desktop sharing is installed on the target Ubuntu system. Run:

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y vino
```

Then use the activities menu to search for *"Sharing"* in system settings.

Alternatively, you can execute the command `gnome-control-center sharing` to bring up remote desktop sharing settings window.

Click on *"Screen Sharing"* to begin the remote desktop configuration.
Make sure that all switches are set to *"ON"*. In case you have multiple networks, select which network will be used for remote desktop sharing. Set a password if necessary.

The *"Allow connections to control the screen"* option gives a remote user the ability to actively interact with a remote desktop. If this option is NOT ticked, the remote desktop session will be set as read-only.
Once the Ubuntu's remote desktop feature is enabled you can optionally confirm that your system is now listening on port 5900.

Open a terminal and enter:

```bsh
ss -lnt
```

The output should be similar to:

```
State    Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN   0        4096       127.0.0.53%lo:53            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0        128              0.0.0.0:22            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0        5              127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0        80                     *:3306                *:*
LISTEN   0        511                    *:80                  *:*
LISTEN   0        128                 [::]:22               [::]:*
LISTEN   0        5                  [::1]:631              [::]:*
```

In case you have the UFW firewall enabled, open port 5900 for incoming connections by runnung:

```bsh
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 5900 proto tcp
```

You should see:

```
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

Comment: Hi Nmath,
Please see below the command:

root@alex-virtual-machine:/home/alex# ufw allow from any to any port 5900 proto tcp
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)

Command is not ambigous, just most of the people do not use this firewall. Personally I'm not using it, but you never know ;)
Regards,
Alex

Comment: I tried to format the answer but for some reason I can not.
Next time I will try to see if there are any tools available.

Comment: AskUbuntu uses standard Markdown: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting - You can also use the GUI tools at the top of the very box where you type questions and answers. You can't use most formatting in *comments* which is why important info shouldn't be added here.  Hope it helps!  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers